# SWIG : How to rename generated Java code according to a regex?

Tags: java, c++, regex, rename, swig

I'm using Swig for generating Java code from C/C++ code.

I get many classes un-human readable, kind of " SWIG_p_f_p_........", and so long.

However, I need my final generated classes to respect some naming rules.

For example :

**SWIG_p_f_p_** should be deleted and replaced by something kind of **PointerOn...**.

Also, in the C++ code there is a suffix ( not generated by SWIG ) which is **FFE_** used for many methods and I need to delete it.

I find in the documentation of SWIG that there is this example of renaming and using regex :

```
%rename("%(regex:/^([A-Z][a-z]+)+_(.*)/\\2/)s", %$isenumitem) "";
```

But I don't know really how to adapt it in my case.

Moreover, having the content of my interface (*.i ) this way :

```
%module FfeFooJava
%{
#include "foo.h"
}
// some typemaps here that use some C++ classes and C structures having suffix FFE
//.....

%include "foo.h"
```

Where can I add the renaming instructions??

**Remark :**

I tried this instruction :

```
%rename("%(regex:/^(FFE_)(.*)/\\2/)s") "";
```

And it changed even some strings values. For example the string **"FFE_OK"** has become **"OK"**. And so I wonder if it is possible to apply naming rules on C++ classes or structures or other, something which would help me exclude strings modification.

Thank you a lot!

Comment: I'm not proficient on SWIG but I have some knowledge on regex. Try this regex: `%(regex:/SWIG_p_f_p_([a-z\d_]+)\\b/PointerOn\\1/i)`.

Comment: If you have stuff that's being wrapped as `SWIG_p_...` that you want to be more intelligently wrapped there's usually a better way than `%rename`, but to give an answer to that I'd need to see a minimal example of a case where you want to do it because it depends on the underlying type and intended usage.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not proficient on SWIG but I have some knowledge on regex.

Try this regex:

```
%(regex:/SWIG_p_f_p_([A-Za-z\\d_]+)/PointerOn\\1/)
```

#### Description

```
     SWIG_p_f_p_([A-Za-z\\d_]+)
     ^            ^            
     |            |            
     |            |            
     |            |
Generated prefix  |  
                  |
                Character class allowing upper/lower cased letters,
                underscores, and digits inside class names.
```

Comment: Logical answer. Class looks suspiciously like \w.

Answer (score 1):

You should likely not have to resort to renaming with regexp in your case. You should be able to get away with exporting typedefs (and wrapper classes or functions via %inline and the very powerfull %extend if necessary but I can't tell from your post). I've shown in several other SO posts how typemaps can be avoided via other high-level (declarative as opposed to procedural) SWIG functionality. If you post some of your .i  code and show which swig_p_f_p etc you get I'll see if I can be more specific.